# sfml 2.3 pollEvent pauses execution

Tags: c++, loops, events, nested, sfml

```
int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "Game");

    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f,5);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    shape.setPosition(400,300);


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        {
            shape.move(0,-5);
        }

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }


        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();

    }
}
```

I'm running debian 8 and trying to make things using c++ and sfml. Whenever I have a pollEvent loop, my while(window.isOpen()) loop waits for an event, therefore the entire thing is unusable. I am aware there are similar questions to mine, but none of their solutions work for me.

Comment: [`pollEvent`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Window.php#a338e996585faf82e93069858e3b531b7) does **not** wait for an event. `waitEvent` does. What exactly do you mean then by "unusable"?

Comment: What it will do is, it will only move the shape when events are happening, when events are not happening, like moving the mouse or pressing a key, therefore it never moves the shape for more than half a second

Comment: @NTS716 So why don't you check for keypresses as an event (ie. in your `while (window.pollEvent())` loop)? See [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php)

Comment: even if I'm not trying to check for key presses, if I do anything in the window.isOpen() loop, it waits for no events to happen

Comment: could it be libsfml-dev as the problem? I downloaded a working game and ran it, and I ran into the same problem.

Comment: It's very unlikely. It works perfectly fine for me on OS X.